# How to open word/Excel/PDF files when click a link in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I want to open a file (like word, excel, pdf) from my code in
 angularjs? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use html link

```
<a href=".. /relativePath/file.xls"  />
```

Comment: if i want to open a physical path documents? apart from project path. how to open??????

Comment: You can use a relative path that reflects where the file is relative to the folder, or you can give  a path from the root of the url. But you can't use a path like c:/ because that will mean nothing to the browser. If the file is not in the project path then you would still need to serve it up via http so would perhaps have a second website to include that folder